# Merge quads ( sprite tile ) to create a new image

Tags: lua, love2d, cartesian-coordinates

In lua you have quads that are part of an image.
I split my sprites using quads
I have a quad per ( different ) tile

My goal is to merge those quads into one image that I update only when a change occurs in my map.

Instead of looping through my map like the bonobo I am I want to blit the map image only once using this sort-of-prerender-method.

Is it possible using love2d ( lua ) ?
If no, is there any other librairies than love2d that would allow that using lua ?

Comment: Maybe try canvases? https://love2d.org/wiki/Canvas

Comment: Oh my god I didnt knew it existed and when I google the question I posted here I found nothing. Really thanks you !
Could you write that as an answer so if people stomb uppon the same question they can see it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try canvases? A Canvas is used for off-screen rendering.

https://love2d.org/wiki/Canvas